# in Qt How to enable ListView and its item all receive MouseArea events?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt 5.6

I want `ListView` and its items all receive `MouseArea` `onEntered`, `onClicked` signals.

I tried the examples and changed:

```
ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: searchModel
        delegate: Component {
            Row {
                spacing: 5
                Marker { height: parent.height }
                Column {
                    Text { text: title; font.bold: true
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            hoverEnabled: true
                            onEntered: console.log("eeee");
                        }
                    }
                    Text { text: place.location.address.text }
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: console.log("entered");
        }
    }
```

Only `ListView` can accept `onEntered` signal, there is no response from its items.

How to enable items receive `MouseArea` events ?

Answer (score 0):

To propagate `clicked` events, you should set [`propagateComposedEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) to `true` to the outermost `MouseArea`.
Guess if the same applies to the `entered` event.